# CASE WHEN after THEN or Select value from other table

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I need to do this:

```
SELECT 
COLUMN1,
COLUMN2,
CASE SOMETHING WHEN 0 THEN 'SOMETHING'
   ELSE
      CASE SOMETHING1 WHEN 'SOMETHING2' THEN (Here I need my value from other table)
   ELSE
   ...
   ELSE
   ...
END
END
AS SOMETHINGSPECIAL
...
...
...
```

Entire select is horribly complicated sorry.

In the place after THEN in () I need to take out specific value from other table.
I have tried almost everything there is from joins, to put there `SELECT WHERE` or `CASE WHEN` statement it always end up with some error.
Keyword missing etc.

Also maybe problem is inside () there is long concatenate:
''

I need to put that specific value from other table into that concatenate.
It either doesn't want to allow me to use other `CASE WHEN` after that `THEN` or I'm doing something wrong.

EDIT (sorry can`t post entire query don`t wanna have problems in work):

```
SELECT 
A.SOMETHING
CASE WHEN A.LIST_ID IN ('something','something') THEN '<A HREF="something?thresholdId=something' || GET_SITE_SUFFIX() || chr(38) || 'task=runSQL' || chr(38) || 'parseParams=true' || chr(38) || 'list_id=' || A.LIST_ID || chr(38) || 'list_name=' || A.LIST_NAME || '"> (MY VALUE FROM OTHER TABLE HERE) </A>'
END 
AS SOMETHINGSPECIAL
FROM SOMETABLE
...
```

(MY VALUE FROM OTHER TABLE HERE) I tried to put there Select statement condition, Case statement to take out that one value from other table but it just gives me error.

Comment: Paste your actual query and error that you are seeing.

Comment: Your entire `CASE` statement seems wrong. A `CASE` statement can have multiple WHEN clauses but only one `ELSE` clause. And your inner `END` seems misplaced. It should be after your () expression.

Comment: Edited original post.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
(CASE SOMETHING
     WHEN 0 THEN 'SOMETHING'
     ELSE (CASE SOMETHING1
               WHEN 'SOMETHING2' THEN (select value from othertable ot where ot.col = x.col)
               ELSE . . .
```

Do note that you don't need nested cases.  You could write this as:

```
(CASE WHEN SOMETHING = 0 THEN 'SOMETHING'
      WHEN SOMETHING1 = 'SOMETHING2' THEN (select value from othertable ot where ot.col = x.col)
      ELSE . . .
 END)
```

Comment: Yes the thing is I tried select statement. I think it isn`t working because it`s like actually selecting one value, but the Query doesn`t know about it so it`s giving me error because it think I wanna select multiple values into one value.

Comment: You can use an aggregation function such as `max()` to get one value.

Comment: The SQL has to be "Dynamic" so specific values can be then translated to other languages. SO previous SQL was like Select this, this, case when this is this then "HARD VALUE" I need to take out that HARD VALUE from other table so its Dynamic. So I could make select like select value from textTable where textID = HardValueID                                                                          But it isnt working and getting me error. If I run that one select statement alone, it takes out the value I want, but if I run entire Priginal statement, it gives an error.

Comment: @user3741301 . . . You should ask another question with more detail about what you are really trying to do.

Comment: Okay so simple question: Will trying to get value from other table Into Concatenate work? So:   Select 'A || B || (my Select)'

Comment: @user3741301 . . . That should work with a scalar subquery that returns one column and no more than one row.

Comment: Just used this solution, thanks so much for this great Answer @GordonLinoff

Answer (score -1):

You could try joining the table that the other values should come from, that's if there is a link between those tables, so these is what you should do

```
SELECT 
T1.COLUMN1,
T2.COLUMN1,
T.The-column-you-want-from-table2
iNNER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T2.cOUMN1 = T1.COLUMN1
```

So there is no need for a case statement, because from what I can gather from your question, you want a representation value of a value from another table

Here is another more specific example,

```
Select 
Transaction.OrderId
Transaction.OrderDate
Order.StatusDescription
From Transaction
Inner Join Order on Order.OrderID = Transaction.OrderID
```

In the above example, the StatusDescription is what need from the "other" table, this can be anything from paid,out-of-stock or whatever status. This status in your first table is represented by a number like 1 for paid, 2 for out of stock etc.....

Hope this helps